# JAXB XML marshalling. Nest tags without classes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to marshall a XML response and wrap it inside another tag. for instance

```
@XmlRootElement(name="stats")
Class A {
String s1;
String s2;
Class B;
/* All getter setters */
}

Class B {
String s3;
String s4;
/*All getter setters */
}
```

This would give me a output like

```
<stats>
 <s1>foo</s1>
 <s2>bar</s2>
 <B>
   <s3>foo1</s3>
   <s4>bar1</s4>
 <B>
</stats>
```

I want it to return

```
<stats>
<response>
 <s1>foo</s1>
 <s2>bar</s2>
 <B>
   <s3>foo1</s3>
   <s4>bar1</s4>
 <B>
</response>
</stats>
```

Is there a way to do this in JAX?